# Is there any live demo/sample applications for SproutCore or Cappuccino

Tags: ruby, rich-internet-application, cappuccino, sproutcore

Didn't find any from their website. I mostly just trying to see which one is worth going with(RIA of course).

thanks

Comment: All good answers. thanks, and I only wish i can give out multiple 'Accepted Answers'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cappuccino Demos](http://objective-j.org/learn/demos/)

Answer (score 9):

[SproutCore demos](http://demo.sproutcore.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, there are also these capp projects: https://github.com/280north/cappuccino/wiki/current-projects (https://github.com/cappuccino/cappuccino/wiki/Current-Projects)

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday a saw a video from MacTV. The guys said Apples MobileMe service was made with SproudCore.